# Comparing columns mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to compare columns in a table.

I have something like this:

```
id    n_emp    paid
1     1        0
2     1        0
3     1        0
4     2        1
5     2        0
6     2        0
7     3        1
8     3        1
```

And I want this result:

```
n_emp    paid
1        0
2        0
3        1
```

In other words, if all paid it should return 1, if all not paid it should return 0.

Can anybody help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MIN(paid)` will be 0 if one or more rows have 0.

```
SELECT n_emp, MIN(paid) FROM myTable GROUP BY n_emp
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select `n_emp`, min(`paid`)
from Table1 Group by n_emp;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01a47/4)